# Calculating beam pointing angle

Tags: algorithm, math, projection, plane

I have images of an elliptical beam on 2 different planes. I do know the distance between the 2 planes (d = distance between plane A and plane B) and I know rotation angle theta (θ) calculated from knowing the center coordinates of the ellipse on the 2 planes. How do I calculate the distance R projected back to the origin of the light source?  I can find what the distance (D) from Plane A to the origin is. I've been thinking about this for a while and can't quite figure it out. I would like to implement an algorithm to calculate R in C#.  The programming part is easy, but the math I'm no so sure how to go about doing it.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question you asked

Comment: I think I figured it out.  It's simply figuring out the angle using the dot product of 2 vectors.  The illustration I drew is really unclear.  I should have drawn 2 vectors.  One going from plane A to Plane B (call it V with (Vx,Vy,Vz) coordinate) and the other just the normal to the plane surface vector (call it N with (Nx,Ny,Nz) coordinate). The value R in my diagram is just the angle phi between the 2 vectors. Calculating cos(phi) = V dot B / (|V||N|)  so phi is just ArcCos(V dot N) / (|V||N|).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is taken with a telephoto lens with axis piercing the beam source so that foreshortening and off-axis effects are trivial, the situation is best viewed from the right side as you have drawn it.  Then you have two similar right triangles with common vertex at the light source.

```
    |^--..._
 rA |   rB| ^^__
    |_____|______o   (Pardon my ascii art skills.)
    <--d-->
    <--------x-->
```

You seem to know or can easily find rA, and rB the in-plane distances from beam source image to elipse center and also d the inter-plane distance.  And you want to know x.

For this just set up the proportion

```
x / rA = (x-d) / rB.
```

Now you can easily solve for x.

If the image is taken with a normal lens from relatively close to the beam source, you need to know the camera geometry so that you can account for perspective effects.  Even then, lens distortion can cause errors unless you know a lot about the camera and do some fancy corrections.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I think my question and illustration are unclear but you are definitely on the right track.  Based on your drawing, I actually want to know rA and rB  (or basically the angle that creates rA and rB when projecting on plane A and plane B.  I actually do know both d and X.

Comment: I only know the location of the center of ellipse on Plane A (XA, YA) and on Plane B (XB, YB) and the distance "d" that separates the 2 planes. I can measure the distance "x". I want to calculate the deviation angle between the vector created by points on each plane and the vector if the beam were projecting straight coming out of the plane in my drawing.

Comment: Thank you @Gene for getting me in the right direction.  Without your response I wouldn't be able to think through the problem and figure it out.  It's annoying how people always assume that Math has nothing to do with programming. You can't code an algorithm without knowing the math.

Comment: Yes.  I've seen too much software that is fragile or incorrect  merely because the programmer didn't understand simple geometry, calculus, or discrete computation.  I think the guys who closed the question missed a chance to improve the art.

Comment: I just want to say. I think your Ascii art is wonderful.